# In alert it is showing the data but not in home screen

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using PhoneGap SQLite, and I am facing a problem that the data is not displaying. The alert(scripts) is showing that the data is there, but it is not showing on the home screen. What mistake have I done in the code?

In jQuery:

```
function get_Emp_List() {             
           $("#employee").empty();
          
           $(location).attr('href', '#emp1');
           $.support.cors = true;   
           $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "one.html",
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: "",
            crossDomain:true,
                success: function (data) {                  
                          $(data).find("employee").each(function () {   
                                                  
                          var emp_id = $(this).find('id').text();
                          var emp_name = $(this).find('short_name').text();
                         
                         
                           db.transaction(function(transaction) {
                                 transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Envy_Emp VALUES((SELECT max(_idEE)+1 FROM Envy_Emp),"'+emp_id+'","'+emp_name+'")',nullHandler,errorHandler);
                            });
                             });                     
                     ids_Dynamic_Emp_List();
                        
                          return false;
                       },
                error: function (data) {
                        alert("error");
                }
            });     
  }

      /*  end Employee list script */
  
   /*ids_Dynamic_Emp_List() method coding Start*/ 
 
  function ids_Dynamic_Emp_List(){
  /*sql start*/
  
  /*sqlite code for dynamic Emp list*/
  db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Envy_Emp;', [], 
  
        function(tx,results){
            
                   if (results != null && results.rows != null) { 
                    var myLen=results.rows.length;
                     for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                         var for_Name = results.rows.item(i).Envy_Emp_Name;
                         var for_ID = results.rows.item(i).Envy_Emp_ID;
                         var for_E_ID=results.rows.item(i)._idEE;
                        /*create table list Dynamically using Sqlitedata base */
                             var scripts = "<a href='#' data-role='button' data-theme='b' data-inline='true' onclick='get_Menu_List(id);' id='"+for_E_ID+"'>"+for_Name+"</a>";
                             alert(scripts);
                          $(".employee1")
                          .append(scripts)
                          .trigger('create');
                        /*create table list Dynamically using Sqlitedata base End*/ 
                        }
                      }
                   },errorHandler);
                  }
                 ,errorHandler,nullHandler);
                 return; 
                  }
```

In HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="emp1">
  <div date-role="content">
    <div id="employee" class="employee1"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would assume from your code that you have more then one employee div?

Comment: Try .html instaed of .append and try adding a dummy text instead of that script, let us know, if it works

Comment: @Gajotres i forget to close the div but my html5 code is correct i knw it is having prblm in my jquery plz help me out

Comment: Your div is correct, I am not talking about it. Tell me do you have more then one div with an id employee in your project? This is important question.

Comment: @Gajotres only one id=employee i have use in my project

Comment: @RobinCSamuel its not working only dummy text is cuming

Comment: one more thing i want to tell that wen any button is been clicked then get_Emp_List() is been call

Comment: Can you show us that function, this one is not that much relevant to this question. I can see you are inserting data into a DB but cant see at what point data is appended to employee div.

Comment: @Gajotres  transaction.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Envy_Emp(_idEE INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Envy_Emp_ID TEXT,Envy_Emp_Name TEXT)', [],function(){
                alert("Envy_Emp table created");
                },function(){alert("Envy_Emp table is not created");});

Comment: @Atul Dhanuka Did you check console? Is there any error after `alert(scripts);` statement?

Comment: @AmolChakane   no error it is showing in console but i logcat it is showing uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'options' of undefined at "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"

Comment: Have you defined css class `employee1` somewhere?

Comment: @AmolChakane i doesnt defined css class employee1 anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this.

In this function call a function and pass data, instead of appending the codes. In the called function, append passed data.

```
function ids_Dynamic_Emp_List(){
  /*sql start*/

  /*sqlite code for dynamic Emp list*/
  db.transaction(function(tx){
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Envy_Emp;', [], 

        function(tx,results){

                   if (results != null && results.rows != null) { 
                    var myLen=results.rows.length;
                     for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

                             appendScripts(results.rows.item(i)); /*call function*/

                        /*create table list Dynamically using Sqlitedata base End*/ 
                        }
                      }
        },errorHandler);
   },errorHandler,nullHandler);
   return; 
}
```

Then append data here,

```
    /*function appends data to div*/
    function appendScripts(values){
          var for_Name = values.Envy_Emp_Name;
          var for_ID = values.Envy_Emp_ID;
          var for_E_ID= values._idEE;

          /*create table list Dynamically using Sqlitedata base */
          var scripts = "<a href='#' data-role='button' data-theme='b' data-inline='true' onclick='get_Menu_List(id);' id='"+for_E_ID+"'>"+for_Name+"</a>";
          $(".employee1").append(scripts).trigger('create');
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Found issue with html 5, change html to,

```
<div data-role="page" id="emp1">
       <div date-role="content">
          <div id="employee" class="employee1"></div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you change that function call to `appendScripts('hello....');` instead of `appendScripts(scripts);`

Comment: i logcat it is showing uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'options' of undefined at "code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js";

Comment: options ??? did you tried this,

 
can you change that function call to appendScripts('hello....'); instead of appendScripts(scripts);

Comment: nthing is cuming i have try tht one also

Comment: Can you check that div is properly closed ? i didn't find the closing tag in the above html

Comment: <div data-role="page" id="emp1">
                <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed">
                     <h3>Header</h3>
                </div>
   <div date-role="content" id="content"> 
        
         <div>
              <div class="select">
                         <div class="heading"style="text-align:center;">Select the employee</div>
                            <div id="employee" class="employee1"/>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
 
     </div>

Comment: my html5 page check it out

Comment: Please change this line and try
`<div id="employee" class="employee1" />`

to

`<div id="employee" class="employee1" ></div>`

Answer (score -1):

Atul,

From our discussion in comments and after looking at 
your following line of code

`$(".employee1").append(scripts).trigger('create');`

One of the following solutions should work for you.

- You should defined css class `employee1`

> If you are finding HTML element using class selector  **i.e
>   .employee1**, then you must have that class defined somewhere.

**OR**

- Modify that line of code as
  `$("#employee").append(scripts).trigger('create');`

> Otherwise use id selector.

Hope that helps.